# Custom php functions in Laravel Queues

Tags: php, laravel-4, closures, beanstalkd

I am using Laravel Queues with beanstalkd. I have following code:

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
Queue::push(function($job)
{
    solve_simplex();
    $job->delete();
});
```

where solve_simplex() is my custom function in php added as extension.

The job is queued all right but when I want to run php artisan queue:work it ends up with:

```
php artisan queue:work
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function solve_simplex() in /var/www/my_site/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/SerializableClosure.php(99) : eval()'d code on     line 2
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/my_site/artisan:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /var/www/my_site/artisan:59
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/my_site/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /var/www/my_site/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
PHP   5. Illuminate\Console\Command->run() /var/www/my_site/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:887
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /var/www/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:96
PHP   7. Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() /var/www/my_site/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:241
PHP   8. Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->fire() /var/www/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:108
PHP   9. Illuminate\Queue\Worker->pop() /var/www/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php:64
PHP  10. Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process() /var/www/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:71
PHP  11. Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\BeanstalkdJob->fire() /var/www/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:119
PHP  12. Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->resolveAndFire() /var/www/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/BeanstalkdJob.php:50
PHP  13. IlluminateQueueClosure->fire() /var/www/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php:96
PHP  14. Jeremeamia\SuperClosure\SerializableClosure->__invoke() /var/www/my_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/IlluminateQueueClosure.php:16
PHP  15. ReflectionFunction->invokeArgs() /var/www/my_site/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/SerializableClosure.php:64
PHP  16. Jeremeamia\SuperClosure\SerializableClosure::{closure:/var/www/my_site/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/SerializableClosure.php(99) : eval()'d code:1-4}() /    var/www/my_site/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/SerializableClosure.php:64
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to undefined function solve_simplex()","file":"\/var\/www\/my_site\/vendor\/jeremeamia\/    SuperClosure\/src\/Jeremeamia\/SuperClosure\/SerializableClosure.php(99) : eval()'d code","line":2}}
```

**UPDATE**

it looks like my extension is not loaded. But it does not load only in that closure. If I run the function solve_simpex() in normal laravel code (eg in controller then it works and extension is loaded....

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. The problem is that superclosure is invoked throught command:

> php artisan queue:work

it is invoked through CLI and idk why it does not load extension.

Solution is run artisan with -d parameter:

> php -dextension=solveSimplex.so artisan queue:work

So I had to tell php CLI to load that extension...